# Exporting MS Access recordsets to multiple worksheets/tabs in Excel results in Read-Only files Using VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, export-to-excel

I am trying to export six recordsets generated by a Do-Loop to six specific tabs in a single MS Excel workbook using VBA.  Instead of updating the single tabs, however, the code creates six open iterations of the workbook with only the first being editable, the remainder read-only.  The recordsets are successfully exported into the correct tab in the desired format.

```
Function ExportRecordset2XLS2(ByVal rs As DAO.Recordset, strSheetName)
Dim xls As Object
Dim xlwb As Object
Dim xlws As Object
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim strPath As String07
Dim strTitleRange,strHeaderRange, strBodyRange as String

On Error GoTo err_handler

strPath = "C:\Database\Roster.xlsx"
Set xls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlwb = xls.Workbooks.Open(strPath)

xls.Visible = False
xls.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xlws = xlwb.Worksheets(strSheetName)
xlws.Activate

'Define ranges for formatting
    intFields = rs.Fields.Count
    intRows = rs.RecordCount
    strTitleRange = "A1:" & Chr(64 + intFields) & "1"
    strHeaderRange = "A2:" & Chr(64 + intFields) & "2"
    strBodyRange = "A3:" & Chr(64 + intFields) & (intRows + 2)

'Build TITLE Row
    xlws.Range("A1").Select 
    xls.ActiveCell = Format(Now(), "YYYY") & " Roster (" & strSheetName & ")"

'Build HEADER Row
    xlws.Range("A2").Select

For Each fld In rs.Fields
    xls.ActiveCell = fld.Name
    xls.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Next

rs.MoveFirst

'Paste Recordset into Worksheet(strSheetName) starting in A3
    xlws.Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rs

On Error Resume Next
xls.Visible = True   'Make excel visible to the user
Set rs = Nothing
Set xlws = Nothing
Set xlwb = Nothing
xls.ScreenUpdating = True
Set xls = Nothing
xls.Quit

Exit Function

err_handler:
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
Exit Function
End Function
```

I suspect the problem revolves around how the function opens the .xlsx file for editing; I have tried programmatically closing the active worksheet and/or workbook in various ways and sequences to no effect. I could presumably insert a break into the code that generates the recordset to allow MS Excel to open then close, before repeating the process with the next tab, but there must be a more elegant way.

[Image of multiple iterations in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpXjY.jpg)

** As a side note, I did post this question also to answers.microsoft.com before finding this forum. Sorry. **

Thanks in advance, Erik

Comment: You can use Data tab > From Access, and then Refresh All when you need the latest data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, this turned out to be series of small issues that resulted in MS Excel holding the workbook file in read-only status after the function would error out.  SOlved after scrutinizing each line of code to find individual lines that were failing.

Answer (score 1):

For each workbook opened you can check the security and reset it so it can be edited:

```
            If Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
                Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
            End If
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jan but no change.  It looked promising conceptually, but the function still opens multiple read-only iterations of the same workbook - each open to the newly updated worksheet, but not reflecting the changes generated by updating the other worksheet.

Comment: Did you have the restricted workbook active when VBA was looking at it?

Comment: Yes & No.  MS Excel is closed when the initial function (not shown) drops the first recordset to the ExportRecordset2XLS2 function. So, no.  As the first function continues to cycle through a do-loop to create custom recordsets, Excel would be active at that time. So yes.  The initial function creates 5 recordsets to export to those specific tabs.

Comment: As a side note, when I restarted my laptop this morning, windows launched something like 30 instances of MS Excel, which leads me to believe that I am not correctly closing MS Excel programmatically leaving a bunch of processes dangling.

Comment: I solved the later problem by adding script into the error handler to close and quit excel so I didn't leave any processes dangling...  err_handler:
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    xlwb.Close
    xls.Quit
    Exit Function

Answer (score 0):

Try this methodology and feedback.

```
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rstMgr As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String, strTemp As String, strMgr As String

' Replace PutEXCELFileNameHereWithoutdotxls with actual EXCEL
' filename without the .xls extension
' (for example, MyEXCELFileName, BUT NOT MyEXCELFileName.xls)
Const strFileName As String = "PutEXCELFileNameHereWithoutdotxls"

Const strQName As String = "zExportQuery"

Set dbs = CurrentDb

' Create temporary query that will be used for exporting data;
' we give it a dummy SQL statement initially (this name will
' be changed by the code to conform to each manager's identification)
strTemp = dbs.TableDefs(0).Name
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & strTemp & "] WHERE 1=0;"
Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef(strQName, strSQL)
qdf.Close
strTemp = strQName

' *** code to set strSQL needs to be changed to conform to your
' *** database design -- ManagerID and EmployeesTable need to
' *** be changed to your table and field names
' Get list of ManagerID values -- note: replace my generic table and field names
' with the real names of the EmployeesTable table and the ManagerID field
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT ManagerID FROM EmployeesTable;"
Set rstMgr = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)

' Now loop through list of ManagerID values and create a query for each ManagerID
' so that the data can be exported -- the code assumes that the actual names
' of the managers are in a lookup table -- again, replace generic names with
' real names of tables and fields
If rstMgr.EOF = False And rstMgr.BOF = False Then
      rstMgr.MoveFirst
      Do While rstMgr.EOF = False

' *** code to set strMgr needs to be changed to conform to your
' *** database design -- ManagerNameField, ManagersTable, and
' *** ManagerID need to be changed to your table and field names
' *** be changed to your table and field names
            strMgr = DLookup("ManagerNameField", "ManagersTable", _
                  "ManagerID = " & rstMgr!ManagerID.Value)

' *** code to set strSQL needs to be changed to conform to your
' *** database design -- ManagerID, EmployeesTable need to
' *** be changed to your table and field names
            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM EmployeesTable WHERE " & _
                  "ManagerID = " & rstMgr!ManagerID.Value & ";"
            Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs(strTemp)
            qdf.Name = "q_" & strMgr
            strTemp = qdf.Name
            qdf.SQL = strSQL
            qdf.Close
            Set qdf = Nothing

' Replace C:\FolderName\ with actual path
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                  strTemp, "C:\FolderName\" & strFileName & ".xls"
            rstMgr.MoveNext
      Loop
End If

rstMgr.Close
Set rstMgr = Nothing

dbs.QueryDefs.Delete strTemp
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing
```

Comment: I suspect that this doesn't get after the problem, which is file write-access issue.  The export part is straightforward.  I'll give it a try in a few minutes, though.  Thanks for your input.